# Use methods withohut refreshing the page

Tags: c#, asp.net, page-refresh

I'm working on a web page .
I need to be able to make some changes on the page when menu changed / on button click.

The problem is when I use :

```
MyDropdownList.SelectedIndexChanged += MyDropdownList_change;

//and 

private void packageTypeList_Change(object sender, EventArgs e){}
```

When I choose the item on a list all the page is reloaded. 
I need it only go to the function and make some html changes.

- I so solutions with Ajax/jquery but it's not good for me , I have to do the change from c#.

Is there a way to do it ?

Comment: It`s not possible without any Ajax/Websocket, you have to refresh the page.

Comment: Does the selection requires some code to be executed on server side, which cannot be done using javascript/jquery etc? What does the list change do on the server side?

Comment: Use [`asp:UpdatePanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I'm uploading some data making many lists of objects. I need to get the selected value from user and put data on the screen.